# Set PhpStorm Auto Complete to draw from specific directory.

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have recently began using PhpStorm as my development IDE as that is what the people at my new workplace use. So far I really like it, there are some pretty useful features that I didn't see in any of the free alternatives.

One of the most useful features is of course code autocomplete. What I would like to know is if it is possible to point the autocomplete to draw from a specific directory and it's subdirectories in a project and ignore the others.

Let me explain the structure of my project:

```
/branches
/trunk
/trunk/*bunch of directories here with various modified and customized classes for specific clients.
/trunk/website *This is the code that development actually works on*
```

So, what happens is if I control-click on a class declaration I will see `many implementations` which is expected because of how the project is structured, the auto complete is looking through all the files and finding custom or deprecated classes of the same name. I have to manually look through and find the one that maps to /trunk/website. What I would like to do is tell the auto complete to just look in /trunk/website when populating it's list. I Googled around for this but couldn't find anything, but thought maybe it would be worth making a post here in case someone else has had a similar situation and found a work-around. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about is *Exclude directories* feature. Go to the **Project** view, navigate to the directory which you don't need to be index (thus, autocomplete won't offer matches from there), right click on that directory and select **Mark Directory As** > **Excluded**.

Later you can manage those in **Project Settings** > **Directories**.